# Using ASIDownloadCache offline

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, asihttprequest

I want to get a JSON and cache it when the Internet is available or use cache if it's not. I used this code, but request's responseString is always null when I'm offline. (Documentation says it works only if server returns 200 or 300 response.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
```

Any idea to get the cached data when there's no network connection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:]
```

To get the path to the cache on disk. If there is no cached data, it will return `nil`.

Comment: Excellent for returning stale cached data as a last resort if the server is down

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the request is explicitly cached permanently (across application sessions). To set this:

```
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
```

Once the request is cached, it will immediately return the cached data as long as your download cache's policy falls back to the cache when a remote connection fails. `[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]` should already be set to the default cache policy, which handles this case sufficiently well.

Comment: This is not enough if the server goes offline and the data has an *expires:* header. The request will return nil.

Comment: By now people shouldn't really be using `ASIHTTPRequest` at all. Switch to something like [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: @BurakSARICA Yes. [`AFURLConnectionOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html) implements the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. To modify the caching behaviour, see [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001695-BJBHBFJA), which you pass to the [`AFURLConnectionOperation` constructor](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/initWithRequest:).